# Custom user queries in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have built an Access database which prevents my users from doing anything in the system other than the specific things that I have allowed them to access (I have disabled the navigation pane and some other features, such as the ability to create queries).

I want to know if it is possible to preserve these limitations whilst allowing my users to create and run their own queries.

I am aware that this can be set up via pre-built parameter queries which are incorporated into a form and which allows users to enter their own parameters, but this isn't quite what I need.

Do say if my question isn't clear enough and I will add more details.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's impossible to protect 100% the application against user with good knowledge without creating compiled version. If you need to eneble, for instance, only Query designer, you cannot compile.

What you can do:

- Create your own ribbon menu with only allowed commands
- Disable system ribbon
- Disable all unnecessary File menu items
- Disable bypass key

In this case user will be able to create/modify only allowed objects. But it's quite easy to enable bypass key and then enable full system menu if you know how. Most of regular users don't know even about bypass key

Comment: Tables, queries and macros *can* be created in a compiled frontend (mde / accde). I think that's the way to go.